# Define $a(n) = 2^{2^n}+1$. Prove for all natural $n>1$ we have $a(n) = a(0) a(1) ... a(n-1)+2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I honestly am not sure where to start with this. I tried using induction and plug in k+1 for every n but it just gets messy and confusing and doesn't go anywhere. Is there anyone who might understand this a bit?

Comment: Big hint: Can you turn the product into a sum - try some low values and keep track of the powers of $2$ as you multiply out.

Comment: This is a standard exercise on induction. It may be easier to see what's going on if you rewrite the claim to read
$$a_n-2=a_0a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1}.$$
As in $17-2=3\cdot5$, $257-2=3\cdot5\cdot17$ et cetera. Use the factorization $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ to get to a form, where the induction hypothesis can be applied.

Comment: The first thing you do when you do induction is to work out the value of $a(0)$, so in your question you should have said $a(0)=?$ where $?$ is your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is a rather simple induction. We have $a_{0}=3$,  $a_{1}=5$ , $a_{k}=a_{0}a_{1}...a_{k-1}+2$. and $ a_{k+1}=a_{0}...a_{k-1}a_{k}+2$. We have that
$a_{k+1}=2^{2^{k+1}}+1$ and $a_{0}.....a_{(k-1)}a_{k}+2=(a_{k}-2)a_{k}+2=(2^{2^{k}}+1-2)(2^{^{2^{k}}}+1)+2=2^{2^{k+1}}-1+2$ which are equal! Therefore P(k) implies P(k+1) and we are done!